# Ridge plot: sort by value / rank

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ridgeline-plot

I have a data set which I uploaded [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camminady/2e3aeab04fc3f5d3023ffc17860f0ba4/raw/97161888935c52407b0a377ebc932cc0c1490069/poll.csv) as a gist in CSV format.
It is the extracted form of the PDFs provided in the YouGov article ["How good is 'good'?"](https://yougov.co.uk/topics/lifestyle/articles-reports/2018/10/02/how-good-good). People where asked to rate words (e.g. "perfect", "bad") with a score between 0 (very negative) and 10 (very positive). The gist contains exactly that data, i.e. for every word (column: Word) it stores for every ranking from 0 to 10 (column: Category) the number of votes (column: Total).

I would usually try to visualize the data with matplotlib and Python since I lack knowledge in R, but it seems that ggridges can create way nicer plots than I see myself doing with Python.

Using:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

YouGov <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camminady/2e3aeab04fc3f5d3023ffc17860f0ba4/raw/97161888935c52407b0a377ebc932cc0c1490069/poll.csv")

ggplot(YouGov, aes(x=Category, y=Word, height = Total, group = Word, fill=Word)) + 
  geom_density_ridges(stat = "identity", scale = 3)
```

I was able to create this plot (which is still far from perfect):
[image]

Ignoring the fact that I have to tweak the aesthetics, there are three things I struggle to do:

1. Sort the words by their average rank.
2. Color the ridge by the average rank.
3. Or color the ridge by the category value, i.e. with varying color.

I tried to adapt the suggestions from [this source](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html), but ultimately failed because my data seems to be in the wrong format: Instead of having single instances of votes, I already have the aggregated vote count for each category.

I hope to end up with a result closer to this plot, which satisfies criteria 3 ([source](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html)):
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took me a little while to get there myself. The key for me way understanding the data and how to order `Word` based on the average `Category` score. So let's look at the data first:

```
> YouGov
# A tibble: 440 x 17
      ID Word  Category Total  Male Female `18 to 35` `35 to 54` `55+`
   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0 Incr~        0     0     0      0          0          0     0
 2     1 Incr~        1     1     1      1          1          1     0
 3     2 Incr~        2     0     0      0          0          0     0
 4     3 Incr~        3     1     1      1          1          1     1
 5     4 Incr~        4     1     1      1          1          1     1
 6     5 Incr~        5     5     6      5          6          5     5
 7     6 Incr~        6     6     7      5          5          8     5
 8     7 Incr~        7     9    10      8         10          7    10
 9     8 Incr~        8    15    16     14         13         15    16
10     9 Incr~        9    20    20     20         22         18    19
# ... with 430 more rows, and 8 more variables: Northeast <dbl>,
#   Midwest <dbl>, South <dbl>, West <dbl>, White <dbl>, Black <dbl>,
#   Hispanic <dbl>, `Other (NET)` <dbl>
```

Every Word has a row for every Category (or score, 1-10). The Total provides the number of responses for that Word/Category combination. So although there were no responses where the word "Incredible" scored zero there is still a row for it.

Before we calculate the average score for each Word we calculate the product of Category and Total for each Word-Category combination, let's call it Total Score. From there, we can treat `Word` as a factor, and *reorder* based on the average Total Score using `forcats`. After that, you can plot your data just as you did.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

YouGov <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camminady/2e3aeab04fc3f5d3023ffc17860f0ba4/raw/97161888935c52407b0a377ebc932cc0c1490069/poll.csv")

YouGov %>% 
  mutate(total_score = Category*Total) %>% 
  mutate(Word = fct_reorder(.f = Word, .x = total_score, .fun = mean)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Category, y=Word, height = Total, group = Word, fill=Word)) + 
  geom_density_ridges(stat = "identity", scale = 3)
```

[image]

By treating Word as a factor we reordered the Words based on their mean Category. ggplot also orders colors accordingly so we don't have to modify ourselves, unless you'd prefer a different color palette.

Comment: @k1next No problem, glad it helps!

Answer (score 3):

The other solution is exactly correct. I just wanted to point out that you can call `fct_reorder()` from within `aes()` for an even more compact solution. However, you need to do it twice if you want to change fill color by position along the y axis.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

YouGov <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camminady/2e3aeab04fc3f5d3023ffc17860f0ba4/raw/97161888935c52407b0a377ebc932cc0c1490069/poll.csv")

ggplot(YouGov,
  aes(
    x = Category,
    y = fct_reorder(Word, Category*Total, .fun = sum),
    height = Total,
    fill = fct_reorder(Word, Category*Total, .fun = sum)
  )) + 
  geom_density_ridges(stat = "identity", scale = 3) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If instead you want to color by x position, you can do something like the following. It just doesn't look as nice as the temperature example because the x values come in discrete steps.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

YouGov <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camminady/2e3aeab04fc3f5d3023ffc17860f0ba4/raw/97161888935c52407b0a377ebc932cc0c1490069/poll.csv")

ggplot(YouGov,
  aes(
    x = Category,
    y = fct_reorder(Word, Category*Total, .fun = sum),
    height = Total,
    fill = stat(x)
  )) + 
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(stat = "identity", scale = 3) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "C")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>